# how to stop text animation in css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My animation is not ending at the end of text what do I do to make it stop after displaying some text.

```css
h2 {
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3vw #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #01fe87;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0vw #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 6s linear;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  70%,
  90% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 data-text="Hi..">Hi..</h2>
```

I'm a beginner so don't know a lot of things

Comment: I tested your code and the animation does end after displaying "Hi..", can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: yeah the problem is that I dont want to erase the "Hi.." after the animation.

Comment: Hmm "Hi.." is still there after the animation on my end, but if it doesn't work for you try adding "animation-fill-mode: forwards" after "animation: animate 6s linear", it will keep the last frame of the animation when the animation ended.

Comment: @keyframes width:0 is causing it to disaappear

Comment: I tried the "animation-fill-mode: forwards "but it is still not working, when you wait for like 6sec after "Hi.." is displayed, the animation come to the starting point and it erases the "hi.." . but I wanna keep the "hi.." until I refresh my page.

Comment: – Bharat I tried it still not working, clear the"width:0" line still erasing

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2 {
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3vw #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #01fe87;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0vw #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 6s linear;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  70%,
  90% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 data-text="Hi Atih <3">Hi Atih <3</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just played with width and it works
width: 0; was causing the issue

```css
h2 {
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3vw #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}




h2 {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #01fe87;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0vw #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 6s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 data-text="Hi..">Hi..</h2>
```